# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for java.lang.Enum<T>

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am facing one issue with enum in Kotlin. Issue seems like silly but may be i am missing some code snippet to make it work. This is my json data

```
    "CustomerData": [
      {
        "token": "token_data1",
        "role": "Admin"
      },
      {
        "contactUUID": "token_data2",
        "role": "User"
      }
    ]
```

One Kotlin data class as below

```
@JsonInclude
enum class UserRole(val userRoleDesc: String) {

@SerializedName("Admin")
ADMIN("Admin"),

@SerializedName("User")
USER("User"),

@SerializedName("unknown")
UNKNOWN("unknown");
}
```

and i am Using this enum class as below

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
data class CustomerAssociate (
        val contactUUID: String,
        val role: Enum<UserRole>?
)
```

But i am getting below errors

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for java.lang.Enum<T>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:228)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
```

Can some one help me out to get rid this.? Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: where you used this `UserRole` object?

Comment: @Moinkhan..I have updated my question..Plz have look

Comment: problem in your declaration ..
just use `val role: UserRole?`

No need to wrap it again with enum

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your declaraion..

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
data class CustomerAssociate (
        val contactUUID: String,
        val role: UserRole? // instead of your code 'val role: Enum<UserRole>?'
)
```

Comment: are you using jackson or gson?

Comment: I am using Gson 2.8.5